# Finding the meaning of a command argument

Tags: man

When reading through other people's code I often wonder if there is a quick way to find the definition of a particular command *argument*.

For example:
Let's say I know what `some_command` does, but I don't know what the `-x` argument means.
`man some_command` will certainly provide the answer, but scrolling through manual pages to find an obscure argument can be time-consuming.

Is there a quicker solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this will help you https://askubuntu.com/a/1281460/283843

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect!  I didn't realize that you could use the slash / with man, and that makes it all super-easy (the grep options are not straightforward).  If you want to make your comment the answer, I'll accept it.